# Can PHP graphics functions be used to create animated graphics?

Tags: php, animation, graphics, visualization

Would like to create an animated display for some data visualization using PHP graphics functions.

A static generated image is displayed after the PHP program completes, but if I issue a imagepng($canvas) function call after each element is generated, in order to show dynamically the visualized process, only the first generated image shows.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
    header("Content-type:image/png");
    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(900, 900);
    if($canvas && imagefilter($canvas, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 255, 255, 255)) {
        $red  =ImageColorAllocate($canvas,    255,   0,   0);
        $green=ImageColorAllocate($canvas,      0, 255,   0);
        $blue =ImageColorAllocate($canvas,      0,   0, 255);

        $r = 50;
        $n = 0;
        $y = 400;

        for ($x=50; $x<=850; $x+=60) {
            if(++$n % 3 == 1) $color = $red;
            if(  $n % 3 == 2) $color = $green;
            if(  $n % 3 == 0) $color = $blue;
            imagefilledellipse($canvas, $x, $y, $r, $r, $color);
            imagepng($canvas);
            if($n % 3 == 0) $x += 40;
        }
    }
    header("Content-type:image/png");
    imagepng($canvas);
    imagedestroy($canvas);
?>
```

Comment: An animated gif is possible but that is how far PHP goes in that matter

Comment: to make an animated gifs using php , please take a look at https://github.com/krakjoe/ui

Comment: [Motion JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) or MPNG might be options in a very limited set of use cases.

Comment: Thank you. Will try the animated GIF workaround.

Comment: Is there a way in PHP to write to a directory GIF screen shot files of each step in the animation and later combine the files into an animated GIF with an animated GIF making tool (there are many)?